# Subsets and simple set operations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that the following two statements are false but I am not sure why. What edge cases for sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ would make the statements false? Let A, B, and C be languages over some alphabet Σ.

$$A(B ∩ C) ⊇ AB ∩ AC$$

$$A^∗ ∪ B^∗ ⊇ (A ∪ B)^*$$

Comment: What do *your* notations $AB$ and $A^\ast$ mean?

Comment: AB is the concatenation of sets A and B, A* is all the strings over the set

Comment: What is an edgecase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A counter example for the first is A = {a,aa}, B = {b}, C = {ab}.
A counter example for the second is A = {a}, B = {b}.